# Clear search bar tool on google map after having searched for a place

Tags: jquery, google-maps, search, javascript-objects

I built a search bar for my map in jQuery which is integrated with the javascript object inside my map in order to display each place I indicated in my map as a marker. The problem is that, when I've finished my research and I want to start another the sidebar that I've created won't disappear. Plus I would like that my search tool will display a "No results were found" message when a user won't find my shop in his city (my search is based on city).

So far my code is:

```
$('#geocomplete').keyup(function() {
    var searchField = $('#geocomplete').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    var output = '<div class="searchresults">';
    if (searchField.length == 0) {
        $("#legend").append("<p>No results were found.</p>");
        $(".searchresults").css("display", "none");
    } else {
        $.each(markers, function(key, markers) {
            if (markers.city.search(myExp) != -1) {
                output += '<div>';
                output += '<h2>'+ markers.city +'</h2>';
                output += '<div>'+ markers.html +'</div>';
                output += '</div>';
            }
        });
    }
    output += '</div>';
    $('#legend').html(output);
});
```

An example of one of my place is:

```
var markers = [
{
    "html": '<some html></some html>',
    "title": 'The place',
    "lat": '44.501345',
    "lng": '-80.215064',
    "city": 'Collingwood'
}..
```

You can see my app in action at this page:

http://choosechickapea.com/shop-chickapea/

UPDATE:

I'm trying a different approach:

```
$('#geocomplete').keyup(function() {
    // get the value insert by the client
    var searchField = $('#geocomplete').val();
    // regular expression to ignore upper or lower case
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    // create a div where to append the results
    var output = '<div class="searchresults">';
    // display the result by default
    $(".searchresults").css("display", "block");
    // loop through the results
    $.each(markers, function(key, markers) {
        // in the case the client after the research, want to find another city and he will start from the beggining in that case delete the div and display a no search found message
        if (markers.city.search(myExp) == -1) {
            $(".searchresults").append("<p class='noresults'>No results were found.</p>");
            $(".searchresults").css("display", "none");
        } else {
            // in the other cases display the results
            output += '<div>';
            output += '<h2>'+ markers.city +'</h2>';
            output += '<div>'+ markers.html +'</div>';
            output += '</div>';
        }
    });
    output += '</div>';
    $('#legend').html(output);
});
```

It still doesn't work but the point is when anyone, after having searched for a place, want to find another place (another city in this case) and he will delete the previous search (search=-1) I want to delete the div I created for the search or I want to display a no results found message.

Anyone who has worked with this particular API? Javascript Object, google maps and jquery in order to retrieve some data from a client side prospective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your display:none is never canceled, I suggest you to first ensure that yours suggestions are visible, then do your if:

```
$('#geocomplete').keyup(function() {
    // your init stuff

    // ensure that your results are visible by default
    $(".searchresults").css("display", "block");

    if (searchField.length == 0) {
        // your fail stuff
    } else {
        // your success stuff
```

Alternatively, you can put the display:block in the success part.

Comment: Nothing has changed, I'm trying a different approach:
I will update my question!